# jquery ajax refreshing page content

Tags: jquery, ajax

am having a jquery Ajax call for changing the content of a div ,functionality wise everything is working fine but ,when ever div is replaced with new content the page get little shake and the and the view position get changed a little .The content that get refreshed is given below ,i mean the html response that i get after ajax call.

```
<div class="booksFrame">
<a href="Magazine/magazinedetail/magazine_id/3"><img src="XXXXXX" alt="Pachakuthira" title="Pachakuthira" /></a>
</div>
<div class="booksFrame">
<a href="Magazine/magazinedetail/magazine_id/43"><img src="XXXXXX" alt="Toms Classics" title="Toms Classics" /></a>
</div>
<div class="booksFrame">
<a href="Magazine/magazinedetail/magazine_id/34"><img src="XXXXXX" alt="The Sunday Indian (English)" title="The Sunday Indian (English)" /></a>
</div>
<div class="booksFrame">
<a href="Magazine/magazinedetail/magazine_id/26"><img src="XXXXXX" alt="Travel Plus" title="Travel Plus" /></a>
</div>
<div class="rightArrow"><img src="XXXXXX" alt="next" title="next" id="next2" onclick="javascript:nextTopseller(this);" /></div>
<input type="hidden" value="6" id="page_number_topseller"  />
```

my function for ajax call.

```
function latestArrivalNext(next)
        {
         $("#previous").css("display", "block");
            if($('#page_number').val())
            {
                page  = Number($('#page_number').val());
                page  = page+1; 
                /*alert(page);*/
                $("#ajax_container").html('<img src="/public/images/loading.gif" />').fadeIn('fast');
            }
            else
            page        = 2;
            $.ajax
            ({
                type: "POST",
                url: "index/scrollnewrelease",
                data: "page="+page,
                success: function(msg)
                {
                /*alert(msg);*/
                if(msg!=0)
                {   /*alert(msg);*/
                    $("#ajax_container").html(msg).fadeIn('slow');
                    $("#previous").css("display", "block");
                }else
                $(next).css("display", "none");
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: could you show your javascript that refreshes the content?

Answer (score 0):

I have used this long back.  Just give it a try.

adding this IE Only meta tag stops the flicker:

```
<meta http-equiv="Page-Enter" content="revealtrans(duration=0.0)">
```

The explanation can be found [here](http://www.webmasterworld.com/css/3662705.htm)

Please mark as answer if this solves your problem

Comment: my problem is not with flicker, after ajax complete request when it start populate the div with new content the contents come in an nonuniform way..distorted.can i make it smooth.